# Reading different Schema in Parquet Partitioned Dir structure

Tags: pyspark, parquet, apache-spark-sql

I have following partitioned parquet data on hdfs written using spark:

```
year
 |---Month
      |----monthlydata.parquet
      |----Day
            |---dailydata.parquet
```

Now when I read df from year path, spark read dailydata.parquet. How can i read monthlydata from all partitions. I tried using setting option mergeSchema = true which gives error.

Answer (score 1):

I would urge you stop doing the following:

```
year
 |---Month
      |----monthlydata.parquet
      |----Day
            |---dailydata.parquet
```

When you read from `year/month/` or even just `year/`, you won't just get `monthlydata.parquet`, you'll also be getting `dailydata.parquet`. I can't speak much to the error you're getting (please post it), but my humble suggestion would be to separate the paths in HDFS since you're already duplicating the data:

```
dailies
 |---year
     |---Month
          |----Day
                |---dailydata.parquet
monthlies
 |---year
     |---Month
          |----monthlydata.parquet
```

Is there a reason you were keeping them in the same directories?

However, if you insist on this structure, use something like this:

```
schema = "dailydata1"
val dfList = dates.map { case (month, day) =>
  Try(sqlContext.read.parquet(s"/hdfs/table/month=$month/day=$day/$schema.parquet"))
}
val dfUnion = dfList.collect { case Success(v) => v }.reduce { (a, b) =>
  a.unionAll(b)
}
```

Where you can toggle the `schema` between `dailydata1`, `dailydata2`, etc.

Comment: Actually its object oriented design what I am mirroring on hdfs..There will not be just one dailydata.parquet but several others such as dailydata1.parquet with different schema (There are multiple levels which I dont want to replicate all over the HDFS for different objects with same path) and since spark enforces lazy evaluation, wont be reading will be taken care of by proper filters. I am looking for such filters.

Comment: Can there be a `dailydata1.parquet` and `dailydata2.parquet` in the same day per your design (i.e. `/2017/03/30/dailydata1.parquet` and `/2017/03/30/dailydata2.parquet`)? The problem with your design is that you'll need code level filters to create a bunch of paths to read and then `.unionAll` the data frames together with a reduce. I'll add a code snippet into an edit.

Comment: Okay. I think that would be very expensive for spark. Right? I shall go with different directories for both.